Подключение select2 на битрикс
Пишу проект на битрикс. Наверху моего файла у меня следующий код:
<?
    use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset; 

    require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
    CJSCore::Init(array('jquery2')); 
    $APPLICATION->SetTitle("test page");
    $APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css');
    Asset::getInstance()->addJs('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js');
?>

Сам jQuery подключился, но библиотека select2 - нет. Вот ошибка из консоли:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

Как можно исправить? Пробовал разные способы подключения (например, addHeadScript), но ничего не сработало

Скрипты выполняются в том порядке, в котором они встречаются на странице. Если скрипт с вызовом функции $(...).select2 лежит выше скрипта, подключающего библиотеку select2, то это приведёт именно к вашей ошибке.
Судя по всему, в хедере подцепляется скрипт, который использует select2.
Исправить ситуацию можно, переместив загрузку библиотеки из вашего файла в хедер до скрипта, её использующего.
